# Access Violation when calling python function the second time from c++

Tags: python, c++

Below is my function to initialize talking to python. Following is a convenience function to call a python function from c++. The Problem is, whenever I call the InitPython function the second time, it crashes on `callPythonFunction("initWithPath")` with an Access violation. The same happens for any other C++ function using callPythonFunction. If I call `callPythonFunction("initWithPath")` the second time right after the first (still in the InitPython function) the program works as expected. Why does this error occur? Py_Finalize() is called before the second call to InitPython().

```
void InitPython(FString currentPath)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    currentPath.Append("PythonProgram/");
    PyObject *sysPath = PySys_GetObject("path");
    PyObject *path = PyString_FromString(TCHAR_TO_ANSI(*currentPath));
    int result = PyList_Insert(sysPath, 0, path);
    PySys_SetObject("path", sysPath);

    PyObject* args = PyTuple_New(1);
    PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, PyString_FromString((const char*)"E:/Unreal Projects/IntelligentMirror/MagicMirror/PythonProgram/"));
    PyObject* res = callPythonFunction((const char*)"initWithPath", args);
    printd("Result from call: %s", *SFC(PyString_AsString(res)));

    Py_DECREF(res);
    Py_DECREF(args);
    Py_DECREF(path);
    Py_DECREF(sysPath);
}
PyObject* callPythonFunction(const char* function, PyObject* args, const char* module = "CInterface")
{
    PyObject* pModule = PyImport_ImportModule(module);
    PyObject* pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    // pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
    PyObject* pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, function);
    PyObject* pRet = PyEval_CallObject(pFunc, args);
    Py_DECREF(pFunc);
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(args);

    return pRet;
}
```

Comment: Your comment that `pFunc` is borrowed is correct, so why are you `Py_DECREF`ing it?